# What to do with these unmarked repos?

Tags: 17.10, repository

I upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 and I've been left with these entries that are unchecked. I was wondering on what to do with them. Remove them or leave them be? Also, why are there so many duplicates?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Anything "zesty" can be removed (but leaving them isn't problem; as long as they aren't selected they do nothing).

Comment: They're all Zesty. I guess I'll remove them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Softwares & Updates** utility reads entries from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list`. During Ubuntu upgrade, those files are modified by a script and some entries are added or duplicated because the upgrade script is not perfect.

Anyway you can safely remove the unchecked sources as all important stuff are available under the other tabs and as soon you don't want to compile Ubuntu software by yourself (This is the usage of "Sources Code" entries).